# Javascript hide prompts in Photoshop

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

Is there a way to hide all prompts and warnings in Photoshop, when running a javascript?

Apparently, this can be done with applescript, but is there a solution for javascript?

Applescript code:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5"
set display dialogs to never
end tell
```

Answer (score 4):

the application has a 'displayDialogs' property with valid values 'All', 'Error' and 'No'.

```
app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO
```

Comment: Anna, thank you, but this does not work. Also tried using try {} catch(err) {}, still no luck... My problem: Using photoshop's script listner I recorded in a .jsx file some print actions. Just before printing I get the warning "The image is larger than the paper's printable area, and some clipping will occur". I do not whis to fix the problem that causes this warning, numerous reasons. I have to click "Proceed" (or hit the Enter key) to continue, No big deal, but when you do this thousands of times it becomes a big deal. My last hope: Simulate an enter key hit and proceed with printing.

Comment: Yes, I do believe that there are some warning dialogs that still appear regardless of this setting.  This seems to apply mostly to more optional dialogs.  Unfortunately it is the best I know of...

Comment: The more correct approach would be to modify your script to make sure the image is smaller than the paper's printable area before printing...  ETA: oops, just saw the bit in your comment about not wanting to fix the problem causing the error.  In this case I don't have any other great ideas for you.